# How to define a noninformative prior for the covariance matrix

Tags: probability, bayesian, covariance, bayes-theorem

We may have a non-informative prior for a location parameter $u$: $p(u)=\dfrac{1}{L}.$

We may have a non-informative prior for a location parameter of vector $\textbf{u}$ (their components are mutually independent): $p(\textbf{u})=\dfrac{1}{L_1 L_2 \dots L_n}.$

We have a non-informative prior for a scale parameter $t$ (uniform on a log scale): $p(t)=\dfrac{1}{tL}.$

How do you define a non-informative prior for a covariance matrix which is positive definite but not diagonal?

If someone would like to give the Jeffreys prior, please give the full form of it (just shown above).

Comment: Inverse-Wishart is another option. You can alternatively write the covariance matrix as the product $sd * R * sd$ where $sd$ is a diagonal containing standard deviation, and $R$ is a correlation matrix. You may see here  also https://github.com/stan-dev/stan/wiki/Prior-Choice-Recommendations#prior-for-a-covariance-matrix.

Comment: I would like to have a full form of the prior probability distribution for a covariance matrix. Could you give me it with detailed derivation? If you can demonstrate that it is an objective prior, it is the best (whatever it is statistically a kind of proper prior or not)